# Magento - Display shipping only in totals in cart page, remove shipping form

Tags: php, magento, plugins, mage

I've been cracking on this for 6 hours now. 
I would like to remove the shipping form that removes the shipping estimates and have a flat fee in the totals.

I already tried this http://www.danneh.org/2010/08/adding-shipping-costs-to-the-cart-automatically-in-magento/
but no use, can someone confirm if this works or maybe give a better idea?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Just Follow this step to set shipping methods
In your `saveBillingAction()` and `saveShippingAction()` in this condition

```
if (!isset($result['error']))
```

call  `$this->saveShippingMethodAction();` function and

Put this code.

```
public function saveShippingMethodAction()
{
    $this->_expireAjax();
    if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
        $data = $this->getRequest()->getPost('shipping_method', 'flatrate_flatrate');
        $result = $this->getOnepage()->saveShippingMethod($data);
           $this->getResponse()->setBody(Zend_Json::encode($result));
    }

}
```

In your save shipping methods steps.
Hope this will work for you.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I got the plugin working now somehow but will definately check back once something breaks( hopefully not) (: